# the_post_thumbnail() Custom sizes not display correctly

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm trying to display wide image icons from the_post_thumbnail() function. I'm using 'true' value for cropping, but they are not cropped well... I get some strange results with different sizes (I'm trying to use 200width x 150height). If image cannot be display with good proportions (I don't know why whem I'm cropping it? ) then I want it to have exact 150px height always! How can I achieve it? I've been trying with set_post_thumbnail_size() but its even worst...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the critical dimension is height, you have a couple options:

Hard-cropping to the exact width/height:

```
<?php
add_image_size( 'wide-image-icon', 200, 150, true );
?>
```

The hard-crop will create a thumbnail size using the *exact* dimensions. Be sure that all images have a minimum width/height as what is defined.

Or soft-cropping (i.e. "box-resizing") constrained to height:

```
<?php
add_image_size( 'wide-image-icon', 9999, 150, false );
?>
```

The soft-crop with an unconstrained dimension (i.e. `9999` width) will box-resize to the exact *height*, while allowing the *width* to be, essentially, anything. Be sure that all images have a minimum height as what is defined.

Also: make sure that, if you have added these `add_image_size()` functions after already uploading/attaching some images, that you **regenerate your thumbnails**.

Comment: didn't knew there is a valid value `soft`. Isn't that argument Boolean?

Comment: @sisir that was a typo. Fixed. :)

Comment: +1 for the mentioning `regenerate your thumbnails`.